# How to set a dynamic property name in var()

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, css-variables

I am trying to use custom properties based on dynamic values, such as `attr()`.

For instance, in below code, I tried to access both custom-properties based on the current element's `id` attribute.

```css
:root{
  --app-foo: 'Hello';
  --app-bar: 'World';
  }
div::after{
/* expected :
            'Hello' for #foo
            'World' for #bar    */
  content:  var('--app-'attr(id));
  }
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

But it obviously fails.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: JS cannot change CSS. You can change style but not CSS

Comment: @Rajesh *JS cannot change CSS*. Are you sure? What is this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference#DOM-CSS_CSSOM

Comment: Kaiido I like to use the buttons id attribute to complete the css variable's name to acquire the proper css variable to insert into the ::after content of the button.

Comment: @zer00ne Sorry if I'm not aware about it but can I do `document.<styleSheets|someOtherProperty>.selector.someCssProperty = someValue`?

Comment: @Rajesh `document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("ul li::before {content:'\1f4a5'}", 0);`

Comment: Since you know the IDs, because you've set up variable which match their names, then you can simply use an attribute/id selector per-element..? this demo code is not a good example for using dynamic variables at run-time. Matching **specific** ids with **specific** styles is what selectors are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables) does not permit the first argument of a `var()` expression to be anything but a single custom property name that is hardcoded. This means that you cannot choose which custom property to reference in a `var()` expression using CSS, since it doesn't accept a string (or an `attr()` expression returning a string) for a property name. You'll need to set the value containing the `var()` expression using JS.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure the problem is really about naming the custom property, rather than the inability to use Strings in `var()` expressions.

Comment: @Kaiido: Maybe I should delete this answer and close the question as unclear. There's a lot of code and hardly any plain English explanation, so it's hard to make heads or tails of what they're actually trying to do. (But what if the asker has trouble expressing their goals in plain English?)

Comment: No I think you got close to what they want (which IMK is impossible). Look at the last snippet:, they tried `' ('var('--'attr(id))')';` just like if it were `'('var(--app-id)')'` but their version will actually be equivalent to `'('var('--app-id')')'` which is invalid.

Comment: @Kaiido: OK, I think I get it. They just want to make a dynamic var() reference. The custom properties themselves can still be hardcoded, but they want to choose at runtime which custom prop to reference. If that's the case, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Kaiido yes, you are correct in understanding my query.

Comment: @Tygari I completely rewrote the question. Please confirm this correctly describes what you wanted. And BoltClock, I hope it doesn't invalidate your answer (I don't think it does).

Comment: @Kaiido I believe it does, but I feel saddened that you deleted all the work I put into it. <!---*cries*--->  As well as the multiple ways I tried to do it showing more than one way would not work.

Comment: @Tygari We know you've made efforts in trying to workaround the issue, but I don't think it adds any value to your question since there is no real way to do it. However, all your attempts did blur your real question, which is a good one. I am sorry I did delete all this content, but I strongly believe your question is better worded like this, straight to the point. But if you disagree, you can still [rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47707873/revisions) the question to what it was before, or edit it further.